# How do I play HTML5 videos with unsupported formats on iOS?

Tags: ios, video, mobile-safari

When browsing on iOS I find that I increasingly come across sites where the site's video format is not supported by by iOS Safari or Chrome.  At [one such site](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/replication), the error reads as follows:

> The video you are trying to watch is a format not supported by the HTML video tag in this browser.

What is going wrong?  Is there any way to play such videos on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what video you're referring to, as there is no video in your link. But I assume there was a video there when you posted that didn't work.

iOS does only support video-streams in AVC h264, MPEG-4 and Motion JPEG, and only M4V, MP4 and MOV as containers/file extensions. Other apps are allowed to include their own codecs and can therefore play other formats, but most don't.
Mobile Safari does only utilize the native codecs and will only play those formats, and HLS-streams.

There is no official way to get Mobile Safari to play other types of videos, and most likely does Chrome as well. If you can get the direct link to the video you could try use VLC or CineX.

Comment: You are right, looks like the example video is no longer there.  I did find the video again on the new website, but it now plays on iOS, which is good, but obviously it isn't a useful example for this question.  I haven't come across an unsupported HTML video in a long time, so it seems like this is a problem that is going away anyway.